# Folder permision

Tags: permissions, chmod, copy, paste

I am unable to copy or paste in other local disk in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I have tried `sudo chmod -Rf 777 /media/atanu/Study` where study is my local disk name. It is showing permission issues.

Comment: You forgot to tell us what filesystem you used. Is it ntfs or fat? if so chmod is a -linux- thing not microsoft/windows. chmod 777 is -never- the correct solution. when it is ntfs you set permissions when -mounting-. Please follow the correct procedures when mixing microsoft with linux.

Comment: Can you [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1138861/edit) the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -la /media/` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the destination device has been mounted without write permissions. In such case chmods won't help you much, until your device will have `rw` flag.

Use mount to check what flag it has while mounted:

```
sudo mount | grep "/media"
```

you should see something like this:

```
/dev/sdaX on /media/atanu type ext4 (ro,relatime)
```

Just change `/dev/sdaX` to your device name.

If it's `ro` this means it's read-only.

Umount the device and try to mount it with `rw` flag instead:

```
umount /media/atanu
mount -o rw /dev/sdaX /media/atanu
```

Pendrive's or SD Cards sometimes has physical switches, that makes them read-only. You may need to switch them be able to write on them.